# Cant upload, port not found error, ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ide, linux

I have installed Arduino IDE on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have installed it from the tar file (ie not from snap) and I have added myself to the dialout and tty groups. When I look at groups I get:

`adm tty dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare`

I am trying to upload a simple bluetooth script to a Nano 33 BLE, and I have installed the `mbed board driver` and the `ArduinoBLE library`.

Whatever I try, I get an error, preventing me from uploading to the board.

```
Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - /dev/ttyACM0; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port not found.
```

I dont know what else to try, so if anyone has any suggestions, I would really appreciate it. I have googled for a while, and havent been able to find anything that works.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your Arduino recognized at all? "Port not found" does not sound as if your priviledges are wrong. You might like to use `lsusb` or similar to check. Or search the web how to detect USB connections.